# 1D Convolution Neural Network Input Shape Problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, data-science

I am trying to build a 1D CNN for numerical dataset. My dataset has 520 rows and 13 features. Here is the code below.

It gives
"ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_21 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (1, 13)" error.

How do I need to set input shape, or do I have to reshape X_train? Any help is highly appreciated.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20)
n_features = 13
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=1, kernel_size=1, activation='relu', input_shape=(1, n_features)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=1, kernel_size=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=1))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=1)
yhat_classes = model.predict_classes(testX, verbose=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that batching your `numpy` dataset yields rows. Now you use batch size 1, so the generator yields 1 row resulting in a array of shape `(1, n_features)` but you want shape `(batch_size, 1, n_features)`.

Adding a dimension to the dataset before spliting it should fix the problem

```py
X = X.reshape(-1, 1, n_features)
```